# SiteCore Item Serialization

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

I am trying to use the "Serialize Item" ribbon button in Sitecore but it does not seem to work. There is not anything written in the serialization folder. What might be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it has something to do with permissions on the **data\serialization** folder.  As the commenter mentioned you should check the logs, there will probably be some sort of error message if that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and in my case it is due to the item path being too long. There is a constraint of something like 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the dataFolder path in the web.config. Make sure the path is accessible to the web folder.